# How to add parent object in JSON with python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this json which has 3 parents and several child elements under each parent.
I want to add one more common parent for all 3 current parents.

Currently I have:

```
 {
  "Parent1": {
    "Key1": "Value",
    "Key2": "Value",
    "Key3": "Value"
},
  "Parent2": {
    "Key1": "Value",
    "Key2": "Value",
    "Key3": "Value"
  },
  "Parent3": {
    "Key1": "Value",
    "Key2": "Value",
    "Key3": "Value"
  }
}
```

What I want to have:

```
{
  "Main parent": {
    "Parent1": {
      "Key1": "Value",
      "Key2": "Value",
      "Key3": "Value"
    },
    "Parent2": {
      "Key1": "Value",
      "Key2": "Value",
      "Key3": "Value"
    },
    "Parent3": {
      "Key1": "Value",
      "Key2": "Value",
      "Key3": "Value"
    }
  }
}
```

Below python3 code doesn't do the job:

```
with open ("myfile.json", 'r') as f:
    myjson = json.load(f)

myjson["Main Parent"] = myjson
```

I would appreciate if you spread some light on this situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
with open ("myfile.json", 'r') as f:
    myjson = json.load(f)

myjson = {'Main Parent': myjson}
```

Comment: @panta, Thanks for the answer, I am getting the backslash \ in the JSON file when I try above solution. could you please let me know how can fix this?

Comment: @SaurabhBade maybe you have some characters that need quoting inside you json? (Other quotes, ...)

Answer (score 5):

You could just create a new `dict` and map `Main Parent` to your child JSON:

```
new_json = dict()
new_json["Main Parent"] = myjson
```

Comment: Thank you very much. this does the job but below answer does it with one less row

Comment: @Tgsmith61591, Thanks for the answer, I am getting the backslash \ in the JSON file when I try above solution. could you please let me know how can fix this?

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
ValueError: Couldn't fix JSON

[Program finished]```if we don't add [] at the start/end of data and try to parse it, also if we validate we get ```{'Parent1': {'Key1': 'Value', 'Key2': 'Value', 'Key3': 'Value'}, 'Parent2': {'Key1': 'Value', 'Key2': 'Value', 'Key3': 'Value'}, 'Parent3': {'Key1': 'Value', 'Key2': 'Value', 'Key3': 'Value'}}
[Program finished]``` meaning the example you posted looks good. Maybe some issues with the file.